# Making a ForeningKey editable on the referenced entity

Tags: django, django-admin

I have to models that have a FK relationship:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
   # ...
   pass

class Address(models.Model):
   # ...
   restaurant = models.ForeingKey(Restaurant)
```

On the admin I would like to add the addresses on the Restaurant form. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an [inline model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).